# How to get duplicate elements in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, collections

I am writing code in ReactJs
I have an Array of object like this

```
[
{
        createdBy: "DEF",
        createdDate: "2020",
        lastModifiedDate: "2021",
        name: "John Doe",
        section: {
            createdBy: "A2C",
            status: "ACTIVE",
        },
        sectionName: "Mechanical",
    },

{
        createdBy: "ABC",
        createdDate: "2020",
        lastModifiedDate: "2021",
        name: "John Doe",
        section: {
            createdBy: "ABC",
            status: "ACTIVE",
        },
        sectionName: "Mechanical",
    },

    {
        createdBy: "ABC",
        createdDate: "2020",
        lastModifiedDate: "2021",
        name: "John Doe",
        section: {
            createdBy: "XYZ",
            status: "ACTIVE",
        },
        sectionName: "Mechanical",
    },

    {
        createdBy: "A1C",
        createdDate: "2020",
        lastModifiedDate: "2021",
        name: "John Wick",
        section: {
            createdBy: "ABC",
            status: "ACTIVE",
        },
        sectionName: "Mechanical",
    },
];
```

here, the only thing same is the "name", so on the basis of name, I want the duplicate objects to be stored in the new array.

I have tried it like this

```
let temp = [];
for (const i of response) {
    if (!temp.includes(i)) {
        temp.push(i);
        console.log("if loop", i);
    } else {
        console.log("else loop", response);
    }
}
```

but the control never goes to else as it considers each object as different.

I need the first occurrence of an object as it is, but when the "name" element gets repeated, that object should get stored in a new array.

Expected:-

```
[
    {
        createdBy: "ABC",
        createdDate: "2020",
        lastModifiedDate: "2021",
        name: "John Doe",
        section: {
            createdBy: "ABC",
            status: "ACTIVE",
        },
        sectionName: "Mechanical",
    },
    {
        createdBy: "ABC",
        createdDate: "2020",
        lastModifiedDate: "2021",
        name: "John Doe",
        section: {
            createdBy: "XYZ",
            status: "ACTIVE",
        },
        sectionName: "Mechanical",
    },


]
```

Comment: Can you include the expected output in your question. This is a bit confusing - _but when the "name" element gets repeated, that object should get stored in a new array._

Comment: @Jamiec added expected

Comment: You might want to include an example with a second `name` just so we're clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Now your example output makes no sense whatsoever - you have the same name in both results!

Comment: @Jamiec I have edited the question, If the name is getting repeated with same value , I want that object to get stored in another array, like in expected , John Doe was repeated , so it was stored in different array , and that is out output , we don't want unique Objects here, we want duplicates.

Comment: Ok ive completely misundestood this question. There are 3 john doe records in the input, but only 2 in the output. Which 2 are you wanting?

Comment: @Jamiec correct , I want the duplicate ones

Comment: what does "duplicate" mean in this example? From what I can see none are "duplicates". Do you mean "all after the first instance of a given name"? That is not a duplicate by any normal definition

Comment: @Jamiec duplicate in the sense , duplicated by name key .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a `tracker` object for checking if an object with the same name has already been visited or not. If visited then push the object into a `duplicate` array otherwise push into `unique` array. Try this-

```js
const data=[{createdBy:"ABC",createdDate:"2020",lastModifiedDate:"2021",name:"John Doe",section:{createdBy:"ABC",status:"ACTIVE"},sectionName:"Mechanical"},{createdBy:"ABC",createdDate:"2020",lastModifiedDate:"2021",name:"John Doe",section:{createdBy:"A2C",status:"ACTIVE"},sectionName:"Mechanical"},{createdBy:"A1C",createdDate:"2020",lastModifiedDate:"2021",name:"John Doe",section:{createdBy:"ABC",status:"ACTIVE"},sectionName:"Mechanical"}];

const track = {};
const unique = [];
const duplicate = [];

for (const item of data) {
    if (track?.[item.name] === undefined) {
        unique.push(item);
        track[item.name] = true;
    } else {
        duplicate.push(item);
    }
}

console.log('unique', unique);
console.log('duplicate', duplicate);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

Comment: can you pls provide documentation link for tracker Object . Or could you please explain the flow .

Comment: A tracker is a plain object for tracking if you have already visited the item or not. You can see I've declare a variable named `track = {}`. Initially it's an empty object.  While you start traversing the data array, at that time check if the name property has already been assigned to the track object or not. If not that means the item is encountered first time, otherwise it's a duplicate item.

Answer (score 0):

```
let count=0
let temp = response;
let duplicateArray=[]
for (const i of response) {
  count=0
  if(temp.find(t => t.name === i.name)){
     count++
  }
  if(count>0){
     duplicateArray.push(i)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this will solve the particular issue you have but
not use [helprjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helprjs)

```
const arr1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'Jack'}, { id: 2, name: 'Jack'}];
const arr2 = [{ id: 2, name: 'Jane'}, { id: 3, name: 'Rod'}];

mergeArrays(arr1, arr2, "name");
// [{ id: 1, name: 'Jack'}, { id: 2, name: 'Jane'}, { id: 3, name: 'Rod'}];

mergeArrays(arr1, arr2, "id");
// [{ id: 1, name: 'Jack'}, { id: 2, name: 'Jack'}, { id: 3, name: 'Rod'}];
```

Check out the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mergearrays-p130j?file=/src/App.js:598-641)